# API call for ACL roles no longer works

Tags: api

I have an API call to get ACL roles that worked before I upgraded to 4.7.29 (I think I was at 4.7.22). Now, this returns no results:

```
    $entity_id = $group["id"];
    $apiParams = array("entity_id" => $entity_id
            , "entity_table" => "civicrm_group", "is_active" => 1);

    $entity_name = "Acl_Role";
    $result = civicrm_api3_get($entity_name, $apiParams);
```

I'm debugging now, but wondering if anyone can quickly tell me if something changed recently that I need to catch up on?

Comment: I have since learned that the api call works, but all the records in the civicrm_acl_entiry_role are gone. I'm now try to learn why that hasn't adversely affected the Manage ACL Roles form.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are using `civicrm_api3_get`. The standard way for v3 api calling is `civicrm_api3('entityName', 'action', $params)`.

Just try replacing the snippet from above question to below:

```
 $entity_id = $group["id"];
 $apiParams = array(
   "entity_id" => $entity_id,
   "entity_table" => "civicrm_group",
   "is_active" => 1
 );

 $entity_name = "Acl_Role";
 $result = civicrm_api3($entity_name, 'get', $apiParams);
```

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The civicrm_api3_get is the wrapper I put around civicrm_api3($entity_name, 'get', $apiParams).  I have since learned that the api call works, but all the records in the